# Changing a value in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, graph

I made a list of tuples that represents a graph such that `(u,v,w)` is a tuple to represent an edge between `u` and `v` and has a weight value `w`:

```
graph = [('A', 'B', 2.0), ('B', 'C', 1.5), ('A', 'D', 3.0), ('D', 'E', 5.0), ('E', 'F', 2.0), ('B', 'E', 4.0)]
```

I want to be able to change the weight of a specific edge, i.e. `u` and `v`. For instance, changing the weight the edge `('A','B')`from 2.0 to 10. Thus, I tried using enumeration as the following:

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(graph) if v[0] & v[1] == ('A','B')]
```

This one does not work. Also, I am not sure if using enumeration is the easiest way here. Can I have some ideas how to improve this line? Thank you

Comment: You are misusing `&` in your condition. I suspect you want `(v[0], v[1]) == ('A', 'B')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple is **immutable** so you cannot change it, you can however get the indices:

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(graph) if v[:2] == ('A','B')] #list of indices ('A','B',?)
```

Now you can use the following program to set the tuples for `('A','B',?)`:

```
for i,v in enumerate(graph):
    if v[:2] == ('A','B'):
        graph[i] = ('A','B',10.0)
```

Running this in the Python interactive shell gives:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> graph = [('A', 'B', 2.0), ('B', 'C', 1.5), ('A', 'D', 3.0), ('D', 'E', 5.0), ('E', 'F', 2.0), ('B', 'E', 4.0)]
>>> for i,v in enumerate(graph):
...     if v[:2] == ('A','B'):
...         graph[i] = ('A','B',10.0)
... 
>>> graph
[('A', 'B', 10.0), ('B', 'C', 1.5), ('A', 'D', 3.0), ('D', 'E', 5.0), ('E', 'F', 2.0), ('B', 'E', 4.0)]
```

Or construct a **new list** immediately:

```
[(v[0],v[1],10.0) if v[:2] == ('A','B') else v for v in graph] #construct a new list
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. Well explained

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable; you could replace it with a *new* tuple with the values you want, though.

Answer (score 0):

If your graph doesn't change often and you frequently make changes to the edge weights, you could run through the graph once and create a dictionary of indices

```
indices = {(u,v):i for i, (u,v,w) in graph}
```

And use it like this

```
i = indices[('A','B')]
graph[i] = ('A', 'B', 4)
```

Any time the graph edges (not the weights) change, you would need to construct a new dictionary.